# java and .NET webservice interoperability: outputing a decimal with only 2 digits in the SOAP

Tags: java, .net, serialization, soap

I'm making a webservice call from .NET client to a java webservice. One of the fields in the webservice request message is a decimal.

It is set using the proxy request object:

```
decimal value = 3.0
request.DecimalValue = value ;
javaService.Process(request);
```

When the message is serialized into soap, the DecimalValue is set to 3.000000. The java webservice however errors out because it is expecting only 3 digits after the decimal point. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I don't have control over the java webservice.

ADDITION:

The schema of the java webservice defines the DecimalValue as

```
<xs:simpleType name="DecimalValue">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
  <xs:totalDigits value="9" />
  <xs:fractionDigits value="3" />
  <xs:pattern value="\d{1,5}\.\d{3}" />
 </xs:restriction>
```

The webservice proxy is generated by adding a reference to the end point.

Comment: The decimalvalue should be marshalled as "3" if you have all the standard SOAP bindings and using `decimal` from the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.  You will need more information about the schema, the error, the actual data going across the wire.  Also how you created your .net client (did you create from WSDL from within VS?)

Comment: I have no clue why it would marshal as `3.000000`.  It should be marshalling as `3` since it ignores all those restrictions as per the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx you'll need to customize the request object.

Answer (score 0):

Given this example, which was created using that simple xsd you provided:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=0)]
    public decimal DecimalValue;
```

I would change it to the following:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=0, Name="DecimalValue")]
    private string DecimalValueFormatted;
    private decimal decimal_value_int;

    public decimal DecimalValue {
        get { return decimal_value_int; }
        set 
        { 
            decimal_value_int = value; 
            DecimalValueFormatted = String.format("{0:N2}", value);
        }
    }
```

Note: this is somewhat of a hack and if you had to do it for a lot of types, you'd want to create your own format attribute that you could put on data members and add custom type binding for decimal that checked your attribute.  I haven't actually done the attribute method, so that might be more difficult than it sounds.